# Why do cats meow when they are adults?

Tags: behaviour

Meowing for kittens is similar to a baby crying. As human adults grow, they stop crying, but as kittens grow up they continue to cry. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a peer-reviewed paper, but there is a widespread popular belief that adult cats only meows to communicate with humans but never with other cats. Meowing allows a cat to obtain the attention of its human owner and eventually get what it wanted.

See [this webpage from the american society for prevention of cruelty to animals](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/cat-care/common-cat-behavior-issues/meowing-and-yowling) for example or [this quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-cats-meow-much-more-at-humans-than-other-cats).